# Create htaccess rule with brakets in the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a redirect rule for the following URL

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?category=39&price%5bfrom%5d=8000&price%5bto%5d=10000
```

And i am using the following rule

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=39&price\[from\]=8000&price\[to\]=10000
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/advanced/result/ https://www.mywebsite.com/my-new-page [L,R=301]
```

I tested the rule on this website http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

and its working on the tester. But the rule is not working on my site. 
What is wrong with my rule and what should i do to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=39&price\x5bfrom\x5d=8000&price\x5bto\x5d=10000
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/advanced/result/ https://www.mywebsite.com/my-new-page [L,R=301]
```

or with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=39&price\x255bfrom\x255d=8000&price\x255bto\x255d=10000
```

Comment: no it did not work. sorry. also i moved the rule to the beginning of the htaccess so i am sure it is not overridden by another rules

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache ou change browser (because R=301 use cache)

Comment: I just tried it on firefox. when you load the url for the first time it will convert parameters to "?category=39&price[from]=8000&price[to]=10000" then if you refresh it it will get redirected to "my-new-page". but still not working on Chrome

Comment: Try with my second and new `RewriteCond`

Comment: it did work. thank u . can elaborate how it was fixed ?

Comment: I just change `%` for `\x25` (and `%5b` -> `\x255b`). I'm glad I was able to help a little